# ObjectListView - how to remove all objects

Tags: c#, listview, objectlistview

When I remove `Items` with `objectListViewInstance.Items.Clear()`, `Objects` will just disappear visually as `Items`, but they are still in `objectListViewInstance.Objects` collection.

When I try

```
foreach(object o in objectListViewInstance.Objects)
{
    objectListViewInstance.RemoveObject(o);
}
```

it ends up with `NullPointerException`.

Is there any way to remove `Objects` since there isn't any `Objects.Clear()` method?

Comment: In your 2nd way just add a null check and remove

Comment: Take a copy of `objectListViewInstance.Objects` then remove it. You are removing items from collection as you're iterating over it. It will result in unpredictable state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to comments I tried to do

```
objectListViewInstance.Objects = null;
```

and it just works fine :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to remove Objects since there isn't any Objects.Clear() method?

The intended methods are

```
objectListViewInstance.ClearObjects();
```

to clear all objects and

```
objectListViewInstance.RemoveObject(o);
```

to remove a specific model object. However, as Sriram pointed out in the comments, don't remove items from a collection while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

In foreach loop you can't delete item

Comment: this is a comment not an answer